How can I politely decline a request to join my project by a free rider professor
I've been working on a project with one of my co-authors. The prep stage is done. We're about to get to the experiment stage. A senior professor in my group, who I know doesn't have the skill for the project, and has been pretty much a free rider on others' papers, insisted to join this paper. Not only the free rider problem concerns me but also it can make my other co-author (who is important to me) pretty mad. He is senior in the department. How can I politely say no?

Are you faculty or a student? Same for your co-author.

I am junior faculty and he is very senior

Is your co-author at the same institution as you and the senior faculty ?

@Marianne013. Good catch. I've edited my answer.

@Marianne013 Different institution actually

"He is senior in the department" is ambiguous.  Are you talking about your co-author or the faculty that wants to join?  What is the status of the other?

I'm not sure we can really give a good answer here, because it's going to depend on how generally corrupt (in a broad sense) the culture you're working in is.  I expect a good answer for Germany will look very different from a good answer for Nigeria.

This is hard, especially if the professor is willing to act unethically to force his will.
One approach, that is "polite" is to say that you are sorry, but you already have the necessary skills and background in the current group and time constraints argue against expansion of the group (assuming that is true). To sweeten the deal, you could suggest collaboration on a future, perhaps related, project depending on their interest.
You may have to depend on your co-author, whom you say is also senior, to protect you from any fallout and, perhaps, to make an appeal to the head of the department to relieve any pressure or blowback. This might be possible even if they are at a different institution. It might conceivably carry more weight - or not.
If you are tenure-track, you might, however, need to yield in order to protect yourself, assuming this person has power over your advancement. Don't get in to fights that are impossible to win. One paper isn't going to make or break your career in almost all cases.
I was once in a department (as a student) that had a few factions, constantly at war. Luckily those factions had different math specialties so the problem was manageable and didn't affect students. But factions happen.
Caveat: Your description doesn't suggest this, but in some cases such a request could be an honest appeal for collaboration and a desire for a person to learn something new as a "junior" partner, even though they hold a senior position. But that wouldn't involve coercion.

Practical advice, but not always nice to hear.  A good answer to a tricky problem.

I disagree with: "If you are tenure-track, you might, however, need to yield in order to protect yourself, assuming this person has power over your advancement." Need to in what sense? Science is more important than one person's tenure case. It seems quite simple to me to simply do the right thing and not list their name, and contact the journal if they escalate. It seems more likely the department would be supportive.

@CalebStanford, you seem naive about what a senior faculty member could do to affect the career of a very junior member. Lots of posts here suggest that one needs to protect oneself from vindictive members. Fighting with a senior member is seldom productive.

@Buffy Protect oneself, but at what cost? I don't feel that I am naive about it. If it is a question of giving up my integrity or losing tenure - what a sad decision to make! - perhaps I should choose to lose tenure. That's a high price to pay for a small boost with a colleague, however serious the possible consequences.

And I don't think I said anything about fighting with a senior member :)

@Buffy What do you think about placing the blame with the external collaborator? (assuming they agree to "take the fall") Still too dangerous if tenure track?

@CalebStanford Prioritizing the greater good doesn't always simplify decisions. In this case, making a decision based on scientific integrity that ends a person's career might seem like the more noble choice, but we can't know ahead of time what would have resulted from that career if it had not been ended early. Sometimes the greatest good is done by choosing to serve a smaller number of people in the short term to improve the outcomes for a larger number of people in the future.

@ToddWilcox I agree, but to be totally honest with you I find the outlook I'm seeing on this particular case to be quite disheartening. It's a hypothetical scenario that seems quite absurd (to me), but if the rest of the department would really take the senior colleague's side on this matter, then I'm not sure academia is worth fighting for. Maybe you can help me see why that's not the case.

Frame change: You do not have to say yes/no to him joining the project. Say that you welcome his contributions.
e.g.

Dear Senior Professor,
We are happy to hear you wish to contribute to our project. We are
currently in the experimental stage and expect to collect volumes of
data soon. My colleague is going to follow analysis technique A. Would
you be able to contribute with analysis technique B? Results from two
methods would greatly strengthen our paper and set a foundation for
cooperation on the project.

After this, he could return with an actual contribution, and there should not be an issue with including him. Or the problem solves itself.

I guess the problem is going to be if the senior professor comes back with a proposal for a "contribution" that's either virtual or not useful to the project. Then you are back to saying no to them and their expertise.

I'd push for specific asks, here - basically make it clear that if he wants in, there's specific work that needs to happen. It's a diplomatic way of saying no, and then for gods sake log conversations/meetings/etc, so when he agrees, then does nothing, you can make sure he doesn't end up an author.

We are lacking some context on this question. For instance, we don't know if you have previously met with this senior department member, or whether they have made contributions to a similar area or had prior discussions with you in some way, even if those discussions don't merit authorship, or whether their insistence is just a way for them to try to gain a collaboration which they deeply want and see as valuable, and in their eyes, would help both your research and theirs. It would be odd for the professor to just insist to join for no reason at all (presumably they have some reason which they would claim, however wrongly). It seems likely there is some additional context about your department culture, university, and field that would be helpful.
Nevertheless, the core of the question is about how to proceed if the professor has made no contribution whatsoever to the paper and still insists on joining, and I will answer the question on that basis.
In short, I think that you should weigh the small benefit to your career that might come from this unmerited authorship with the cost to your integrity and broader moral judgment, and the cost to the field itself. I outline seven factors to consider below.
First, in terms of the benefits, @Buffy is absolutely right that your relationship with your colleagues is critical to your success as a professor!
But I do have to wonder whether this is really the best way to achieve that.
I don't know the culture at your department, but if this professor is really as pushy as you say (and has pressured other department members similarly), it is likely that others in the department are unhappy with him for similar reasons. Tensions in departments sometimes go far back. You don't want to anger your colleagues, but is it possible you would also anger your colleagues by including this professor?
Second, there is the question of your other coauthor, who you say is senior.
An additional unmerited authorship will equally affect them, so what is their stake in the matter? Ideally, your senior coauthor should be your best ally here. In fact, they are the one who should (again, ideally) do the work of standing up for your case. If you haven't yet, please ask for their advice. If at all possible, the polite decline should come from them and not you.
Third, while it is likely this could anger your colleague, there are ways to do so more politely and pragmatically, to cover your bases, so to speak. I think that @Buffy and @Eriks have given very good advice about pragmatic approaches. In general, never argue or fight with a senior colleague; be firm and stand your ground, but never be rude, intense, or insulting. All you have to do is politely state your reasons to decline and how you will proceed. You could even give them a gift (for example) to express your disappointment that you were not able to collaborate for reasons X, Y, and Z and you sincerely regret that.
Fourth, we get to the more serious issues of your moral status of the decision. Your own sense of ethics has no small part to play in this matter! It would be my worry that if you throw away that sense now, it will only be a guilt that you have to bear later on, a painful grudge that works away at your inner conscience and may even hurt your belief in the progress of science itself and your own academic integrity. Which is more important? I would be very careful before throwing away that belief and integrity away for a short-term gain with a colleague.
Fifth, what you decide is highly visible -- not just in your department, but also in your community and in your field. I wish to point out that, should you go against your own better moral judgment, you are implicated in this too, not just the senior professor. You are guilty of misrepresenting your results and it is to the detriment of the journal and of your field. Depending on this professor's reputation, if there are many such similar cases, this could even later come to light, and this could even lead (in an extreme case) to a paper retraction.
Sixth, there is absolutely a risk of escalation, but then, we come to the the pragmatics of what to do in that case. I wish to point out that, at the end of the day, the path to proceed is really quite simple. You are the one who has the paper login to submit (and no one else does!) With this power, you have both the ability and scientific duty to submit the paper with the correct list of authors and follow the correct scientific process. The professor can counterclaim authorship over your paper, if they choose to do so; but in case of a dispute, this is also something you would work with the journal on. You may even need to be prepared to retract the paper rather than include their name, in case of a serious dispute.
Seventh and lastly, we come to how to proceed in case of a further escalation which affects your tenure case. In this worst case scenario, you do have some options. Document everything; communicate solely in writing, by email; and make the status of the paper and its contributions clear. Communicate with the journal and the editor early on to let them know about the situation; communicate both with your department chair, and with higher ups if necessary, about the situation in advance. If everything is documented, the department may see your side of things and support your case. Fortunately, people have received tenure under much worse departmental disputes. (And if they don't, is this really a department you want to be tenured at?)
